# Augmented reality 3D model from 2D plot

Tags: 3d, 2d, augmented-reality

I found an intresting [app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mclaren.McLarenProject1) on Google Play, see this demo on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=zuquH6rCuO0). Could anybody advice how to do this magic? Any common principles, technics, libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found [Andar](https://code.google.com/p/andar/) library for Android platform which do exactly what shown on video

And another one library [NyARToolKit](http://nyatla.jp/nyartoolkit/wp/?page_id=55) the Java port of original [ARToolKit](http://www.hitl.washington.edu/artoolkit/)

Comment: these are even slightly easier as they directly use QR codes (or similar) to recognize what needs to be shown instead of a drawing ;)

Answer (score 1):

You will probably want to start by reading up on [Camera Resectioning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camera_resectioning).

*Very* briefly, it is the process of estimating the parameters involved in the (non-linear) projection performed by a camera lens. There is the R (rotation) and T (translation) that you may already know about, from perspective projection. In addition, there's also other things, like lens distortion that go into the transform, which need to be calculated (or figured out from the make/model of the camera/phone).

The position of certain features in the printed image can be used to estimate these parameters. Once they're known, just use that as your ModelViewProjection matrix and render your car/spaceship/dragon.

Answer (score 1):

I don't specifically know this app, but it certainly does not reconstruct a perfect 3d geometric car model **that contains an interior and the engine** from these drawings.

Looking at the app webpage, it looks like there is only a limited set of car that you can download and print yourself : the app only **recognizes which drawing** it is (this is easy machine learning and image processing), loads a pre-made 3D model, and displays it. The display is made stable by estimating the extrinsic and intrinsic camera parameters, which can be done via point correspondences (this is not that easy given that they only film a planar surface which should only allow to recover an homography), but can be attempted with OpenCV.